# How to convert Rpush 2.X gem to use Apple APNS/2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

In March Apple is discontinuing the APNS/1 server for push notifications requiring me to upgrade my Rails 4.1.16 to APNS/2.

I currently use the Rails gem Rpush version 2.7.0 to send APNS/1 push notifications. As I am using Rails 4.1.16 I cannot upgrade to the later version of Rpush which supports APNS/2

Does anyone know how to patch Rpush 2.7.0 to talk to Apple APNS/2 server?

Comment: Well 2.7.0 is well behind. What is prohibiting you from upgrading rails? Rails 4 is out of support so it would be wise to upgrade anyway. What ruby version are you using? Maybe you can "upgrade" rpush without stepping up to the newest version, if you do not want to upgrade rails. Looks like [rpush 4.2](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/blob/v4.2.0/rpush.gemspec) has limited rails scoped dependencies but it does require at least ruby 2.3.0

Comment: I agree it is well behind, and there is a plan to move from Rails 4, just not soon enough, in a startup. lack of engineering resources, etc, etc, etc.  I agree with all your comments.  Currently I we are on 2.1.9.  I will checkout a move to Ruby 2.3.

Comment: I know that struggle though upgrade from 2.1 to 2.3 should not be an issue at all. Maybe upgrade all the way to 2.7 (lots of nice new methods and should be fully backwards compatible)